# Django test can't initialize db but I can

Tags: database, django, testing

The title isn't clear, I know that.
I want to unit test my application so I wrote a little test that I wanted to execute. I launched `python manage.py test` but there was an error in the DB :

```
The error was: ERREUR:  the relation « me_auth_emailuser » doesn't exists

Error in migration: authtoken:0001_initial
DatabaseError: ERREUR:  the relation « me_auth_emailuser » doesn't exists
```

(Translated from french)
This table has been migrated using south. For my application, I just use :

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate me_auth
python manage.py migrate
```

I don't understand what is going on, because with these commands I don't get any error... Can someone help me with that ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably at some point you had a relation `me_auth_email_user`, that you no longer have. I imagine you'd get the same error if you were to create a fresh database, and run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate
```

There are two solutions to this:

1. Don't use South in your unit tests (either by removing it from your `INSTALLED_APPS` if you're testing, as below, or by setting [`SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/unittests.html) in your `settings.py`).
2. Fix up the broken migration manually.

A quick and hacky way to remove South during tests is to have something like this in your `settings.py`, below where your normal `INSTALLED_APPS` setting is:

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv:
  INSTALLED_APPS = [app for app in INSTALLED_APPS if app != 'south']
```

In general, testing migrations is a good thing - you should always be able to create a new database and run `migrate` - so I'd strongly recommend considering option (2).